# What is a formal way to write (singlehood)?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, word-meaning

I have a marriage certificate and in one of the cells it has written (Surename at singlehood) in my language, but I think it is not a good translation. So, how do I can write it down on a formal basis?

Answer (score 3):

Probably one of

- "Pre-marriage surname"  (very direct, it says what it means, but not very idiomatic)
- "Maiden name" (the common idiom, but only applies to women.)
- Surname at birth (This could differ from the first, if a person has changed their name between birth and marriage)

(And there should be the general warning that internationally, [names are hard](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/))